# amcharts 4 - Hide/show yAxis is leaving empty space

Tags: amcharts, amcharts4

I am implementing show/hide feature of yAxes using `show()` and `hide()` methods. But the result looks this way:

[image]

Is there a way to remove that empty space between the axes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`hide` simply sets the opacity of the elements to 0. To completely remove the space occupied by the axis, you need to set [`disabled`](https://www.amcharts.com/docs/v4/reference/axisrenderer/#disabled_property) to true on the axis' renderer. Setting it back to false will restore the axis completely.

```
axis.renderer.disabled = true;
```

Comment: Setting `axis.disabled = true` is changing my data appearance. Is it possible?

Comment: My apologies, you need to set disabled on the renderer: `axis.renderer.disabled = true;`. I've updated the answer.

Comment: It seems better but still it's leaving the axis without number somehow. The codepen here - https://codepen.io/team/amcharts/pen/qgXGBy

Update: Okay it seems like it doesn't go well together with this property:
  `valueAxis.renderer.line.strokeOpacity = 1; `